# How do I reference a private static final constant value in Java doc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I've a class something like below, where I would like to reference INVALID/APPLE/ORANGE constants when describing `mCurrentFruit`. I didn't know a way to do this.

```
public class MyClass {

private static final int INVALID = -1;

private static final int APPLE = 1;

private static final int ORANGE = 2;

// Holds APPLE/ORANGE if currently chosen fruit is one among them, INVALID if user didn't choose anything
private int mCurrentFruit = 0;

    public MyClass() {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

Tried {@link MyClass.INVALID} and {@value MyClass.INVALID} both didn't work.

Some help would be appreciated !

Comment: Try `{@link #INVALID}`

Answer (score 3):

Use `/** .... */` blocks for JavaDocs.

[How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html)

```java
public class MyClass {

    private static final int INVALID = -1;

    private static final int APPLE = 1;

    private static final int ORANGE = 2;

    /**
     * Holds {@link MyClass#APPLE} or {@link MyClass#ORANGE} if currently chosen fruit is one among them
     * Otherwise, {@link MyClass#INVALID} if user didn't choose anything
     */
    private int mCurrentFruit = 0;

    public MyClass() {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```